# Implementing a view relationship plugin

Tags: 8, views

Using Drupal 8, I am trying to create a view plugin to add a relationship to an existing view.
I'm basing the code off of this example https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-build-complex-filters-drupal-8 since I haven't found an explanation of how to add a relationship in D8.

I don't have any error messages but I'm not sure what I need to do to get this working.

I have a class file for the plugin at module_name/src/Plugin/views/relationship/CustomRelationship.php

// CustomRelationship.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\views\relationship;

use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\relationship\RelationshipPluginBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Add custom view relationship
 *
 * @ingroup views_relationship_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsRelationship("custom_relationship")
 */

class CustomRelationship extends RelationshipPluginBase {

  /**
   * Relationship plugin.
   *
   *
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->valueTitle = t('Node Revision');
  }

  public function query() {

    $configuration = array(
      'table' => 'node_revision',
      'field' => 'nid',
      'left_table' => 'node_field_revision',
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      );

    $join = Views::pluginManager('join')->createInstance('standard', $configuration);
    $this->query->addRelationship('node_revision', $join, 'node_field_revision');

  }

}
```

And in the main module folder there is a views.inc file

// custom_module.views.inc

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function custom_module_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['custom_module']['custom_relationship'] = array(
    'title' => t('Node Revision'),
    'help' => t('Provide node revision relationship.'),
    'relationship' => array(
      // ID of relationship handler plugin to use.
      'id' => 'custom_relationship',
    ),  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't need to create a Views relationship plugin, although that might depend on any special cases with your relationship.

I've got two custom entities - a student and a school, which have been scaffolded using Drupal console. The Student has an entity reference field (school_id) which relates a Student to a School but the opposite relationship - Students belonging to a School - isn't generated by default. So to create the relationship that can be used in views, I built this hook method:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function school_student_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['school']['student']['relationship'] = [
    'title' => t('Student'),
    'label' => t('Student'),
    'group' => 'School',
    'help' => t('Reference to students of a school'),
    'id' => 'standard',
    'base' => 'student',
    'base field' => 'school_id',
    'field' => 'id',
  ];
}
```

If you examine the $data array, you'll see all the data for all your views tables. It's a big list with lots of array elements. It'll make sense when you look at it. Set a breakpoint in your views_data_alter hook to inspect it (or use dpr/kpr/dpm).

What we're doing is creating a relationship from one table to another, as this relationship currently doesn't exist. I believe that the array element names 'school' and 'student' should refer to the table names we are dealing with. We're creating a relationship data alter and so 'relationship' is the child array element we need to create. Below that is just configuration.

**title** refers to the relationship title in your "Add relationship" modal window

**label** is the default name of the relationship when you create it

**group** is the name of the relationship group your new relationship belongs to

**help** is helper text/description for the relationship

This next bit is important!

**id** refers to the the name of the views relationship plugin you are needing to use. Because I'm not creating a complex relationship (basically a simple inner join), I'm using the Standard views relationship plugin (found in *Drupal\views\Plugin\views\relationship\Standard*).

Finally, **base** is the base table we're creating the relationship *from*.

**base field** is the join field in our base table and finally **field** is the field in the school table we're creating our join to.

So in use, views will create a join that in SQL looks like:

```
INNER JOIN {student} student_school ON school.id = student_school.school_id
```

Hopefully this makes sense and helps you or others out.

Comment: The auto-generated code from console is meant to be modified. There's a file called something like `SchoolViewsData.php` that you could modify the `getViewsData` function more directly rather than using a `hook_views_data_alter`.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom_module.views.inc file you probably need to attach your relationship to the node 'table' so instead of

```
  $data['custom_module']['custom_relationship'] = array(
```

you want

```
  $data['node']['custom_relationship'] = array(
```

... or maybe `node_field_data`